# RecyclerView GridLayoutManager: Individual layout per item count

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I need some help with my GridLayoutManager.

If I have an item it should be displayed as normal in the middle.
For two items these should be next to one another.
[Example with 2 Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKWSJ.png)
From three to four items it should be displayed like a square.
[Example with 3 Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG6Z7.png)
[Example with 4 Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8ILo.png)

If I'm right, this should be the case with spanCount 2. But that with the 5 items (so three in a row) is then problematic

From five items (and up) should each be 3 in a row
[Example with 5 Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf8Wd.png)
**It would be especially good if the items in the bottom row were also in the middle**
I hope someone can help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your span dynamically by subclassing `GridLayoutManager` like this :

```
class CustomGridLayoutManager(context: Context) : GridLayoutManager(context, 2) {

    override fun onLayoutChildren(recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
        updateSpanCount()
        super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state)
    }

    private fun updateSpanCount() {
        val colCount = if (childCount <= 4) {
            2
        } else {
            3
        }
        this.spanCount = colCount
    }
}
```

If you want to center your elements in the last row, it would a little convoluted to do it through `GridLayoutManager`. You might want to check [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) for that purpose. It's a library made by Google itself and has flex box model found commonly in HTML5 / CSS world.